# Can we project onto a component in a product measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have a measure space $(X,\Sigma)$ with a measure $\mu$, and we can decompose the measure space into the product of two spaces: $X=X_1 \times X_2$, $\Sigma= \Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2$.

Is it in general possible to find measures $\mu_1, \mu_2$ on the two components so that for any measurable sets $B_1 \in \Sigma_1, B_2 \in \Sigma_2$, we have $\mu(B_1 \times B_2)=\mu_1(B_1) \mu_2(B_2)$?

Are these measures unique? Is there a canonical way of doing it?

So what I'm asking is if we know that a space is a product space whether we can recover the original measures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A measure $\mu$ on $(X,\Sigma)$ induces measures $\mu_1,\mu_2$ on $(X_1,\Sigma_1)$ and $(X_2,\Sigma_2)$ prescribed by $B_1\mapsto\mu(B_1\times X_2)$ and $B_2\mapsto\mu(X_1\times B_2)$.

These measures $\mu_1,\mu_2$ induce a measure $\mu_1\times\mu_2$ on $(X,\Sigma)$ but it is not guaranteed that $\mu=\mu_1\times\mu_2$.

If equality holds then the measures $\mu_1,\mu_2$ can be called *independent*.

If equality lacks then the measures $\mu_1,\mu_2$ can be called *dependent*.

Comment: This gives us canonical measures on the component spaces, although in the cases I am thinking of (Lebesgue measure on R^2) it is a rather uninteresting one. I imagine there need not exist a working construction in general, but I'll wait a bit longer before accepting.

Comment: Take your time, of course. The spaces $(X,\Sigma)$ and $(X_1\times X_2,\Sigma_1\times\Sigma_2)$ are isomorphic, though. So the first will not be more interesting than the second.